# Change boolean field value with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-fields

I have to add some field value on a form using JS/JQ. I could manage text, number and choice fields but I am stuck on Boolean ones:

```
$("input[title='Title Required Field']").val("Hey my dear");
$("textarea[title='Task Description']").val("Mary had a little lamb");
$("select[name='choicefieldname'").val("Choice#3");
```

Work fine, while

```
$("input[name='YesNotFieldName']").val(true);
```

does not work. Boolean fields have no "title" tag, So I have to use "name". I have also tried with "id" but it did not help.
Also I have tried giving value "1" but still does not work.
Where is the mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.prop` to deal with `boolean` that is for supported attributes like `selected/disabled/checked` e.t.c

```
$('#element').prop('attribute', true);
```

**from jQuery docs, (an example)**

`elem.checked` returns `true` (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

`$(elem).prop("checked")` returns `true` (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

`elem.getAttribute("checked")` returns `"checked"` (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

`$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6)` returns `"checked"` (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

`$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6.1+)` returns `"checked"` (String) Will change with checkbox state

`$(elem).attr("checked")(pre-1.6)` returns `true` (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state